# Call resource every x secons with $timeout and handling promise?

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise

In a Angular app, i have a call to a API. I want to get this call to run every 5 seconds Therefore i should use $timeout, i'm thinking. But I am unsure, as to how I should handle the promise.

This is my call, before implementing the $timeout, which works:

```
vm.products = Products.get();
vm.products.$promise.then(function (data) { 
    // do something
});
```

Then i tried to implement the $interval, like so:

```
vm.products = $interval(Products.get(), 5000);
vm.products.$promise.then(function (data) {
    // do something
});
```

But this returns `vm.products.$promise is undefined`

How should it look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below should work.

```
vm.products = $interval(Products.get, 5000);
vm.products.then(function (data) {
    // do something
});
```

Don't use `vm.products` for having `Product.get()` promise, it would mess with old pending promise if that doesn't get complete in 5 seconds.

```
$interval(productPromise, 5000);

function productPromise() {
    Products.get().$promise.then(function (data) {
    // do something
    });
};
```

Comment: Still returns the same error, "vm.products.$promise is undefined"?

Comment: Glad to know.. Thanks ;)